# What's the name of this tropical plant?

Tags: identification, tropical

Today I bought a tropical plant at a store, but I do not know the name of this plant.

The leaves are not hairy, the stem below has 2 single stalks that has new emerging leaves, but is not rounded like a ball.

Can you give me the name and some care guidance related to this plant?

[image]

Comment: not a peperomia or a pothos.  Are the leaves hairy?  Is the stem waxy and round or does is have a groove in it?

Comment: Perhaps a young hoya?

Comment: @kevinsky Are you sure it's not a young peperomia?

Comment: @JMusser, peperomia stalks are circular with a waxy finish and the stem has prominent raised ring where each segment joins.  Some peperomia have slender red stalks but none of them what I think I see in the photo: a groove in the leaf stalk

Answer (score 1):

how about a ficus elastica, a rubber plant?
There's a lot of color variations out there, I've never seen this one, but it could be new or off-color because of lighting issues